# LED monitor disturbed image, but before VGA is plugged it is OK

Tags: display, vga, led

My monitor shows the setting menu (when I press the menu button of the monitor) very well (clear image)  but the image output from my computer (desktop)  is disturbed (like an old TV that has weak signal). 
My question : can it be a bad monitor. or it is just a bad cable?


EDIT: the image itself is still. But a wave like noise is moving horizontally (about 5 waves at a time).

Comment: Any particular reason you’re still using VGA? What monitor model are we talking about? What’s your computer’s graphics card? Are you using any adapters?

Comment: I just have only a VGA cable. monitor model: Samsung BX2031 (LS20X3UKFV/ZN).Graphics card amd Radon 5000 series. No adapters.

Comment: Yeah, that’s not a proper reason at all. Get a DVI cable and forget about this issue.

Comment: but VGA should work. I just want to know it is possible that the problem is in the monitor itself (that would be a disaster for me:(

Comment: analog VGA it is important to have a good sheilded cable, plus any interferance being induced could possibly be the problem.